# Mongodb Query find()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
    {
            "_id" : 48005550000,
            "components" : {
                    "country" : 4,
                    "area" : 800,
                    "prefix" : 555,
                    "number" : 5550000
            },
            "display" : "+4 800-5550000"
```

I have this and want to find all documents with "country": 4

I tried this

```
db.phones.find({"country": 4})
```

but it gave back nothing

Comment: try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7WC7ZLVeQ3a)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find({
  "components.country": 4
})
```